# Oracle PL-SQL sequence

Tags: plsql

Good Day,

I am trying to use a pl/sql variable in my query (I'm a sql server guy) and here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    nextvalue     integer;
BEGIN

    SELECT submission_seq.currval INTO nextvalue FROM DUAL;

    dbms_output.put_line('test');    
    dbms_output.put_line(nextvalue);

    /* ERROR OCCURS HERE */
    SELECT nextvalue, id FROM TABLE_STATUS;

END;
```

I'm getting the PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this as I used one to populate nextvalue *which* does contain what I want.

Can anyone help me?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 1):

It's because, as the message describes, the select statement is expecting you to allocate the result into a variable.

Try:

```
DECLARE
    nextvalue     integer;
    result        table_status%type;
BEGIN

    SELECT submission_seq.nextval INTO nextvalue FROM DUAL;

    dbms_output.put_line('test');    
    dbms_output.put_line(nextvalue);


    SELECT id INTO result FROM TABLE_STATUS;

END;
```

Comment: Well this certainly makes more sense.  I take it that "table_status%type" refers to a column in TABLE_STATUS.

Comment: yes you want your variable to be of the same type as the type of the column whose data you are trying to save in your id.

Answer (score 0):

The secuence has started?

Change this

```
SELECT submission_seq.currval INTO nextvalue FROM DUAL;
```

for this

```
SELECT submission_seq.nextval INTO nextvalue FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 11g then you don't have to select from dual anymore. Below snippet will work.

```
/* Formatted on 1/25/2013 4:35:00 PM */
DECLARE
   nextvalue      NUMBER := submission_seq.currval;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('test');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (nextvalue);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
    nextvalue     integer;
BEGIN
nextvalue := submission_seq.currval;

dbms_output.put_line('test');    
dbms_output.put_line(nextvalue);

SELECT nextvalue, id FROM TABLE_STATUS;

END;
```